# What Is the Physical Size of a Magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism

With present day materials and technology what is the physical size of a one milli Tesla magnet? How much "power" it has to attract pieces of iron? Please compare it with the objects we have around. What difference in size and "power" it gets each order of magnitude that I go up? What is a weak magnet what is a powerful magnet in this scale?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: If so I feel pretty bad for the students..

Comment: "Retired Teacher" - looks like Mr Jones is not entirely retired yet, and is field-testing his homework questions here.

Comment: @MSalters, ah - a good SE survival tip: always check the profile.

Comment: Wordings may seems so, since I am a retired teacher. This is a genuine question related to engineering of physics. I want to have an imagination of modern tools. I have not read Physics Today since 1992, which had a section about engineering in physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you take a look at the K&J Magnetics website, particularly the magnet properties calculator: http://www.kjmagnetics.com/calculator.asp

Your question has too much ambiguity for a real answer, but I think that perhaps that page will address what you are wondering about.

Comment: I could test many different sizes at that site. Solved.